# How to Integrate AngularJs in Yii2

Tags: angularjs, yii2

I want to use angularjs in my yii2 application. My questions are.
1) Is angularjs fixiable with yii2
2) Which one will the best choice to use routing Angular OR Yii2
Please tell some advantages or disadvantages of angularJs with Yii2.Thanks for suggestions